adaptive design based on non-comparative data
please help to understand the paragraph from FDA guidance on Adaptive Designs for
Clinical Trials of Drugs and Biologics https://www.fda.gov/media/78495/download (Section IV)

This section addresses adaptive clinical trial designs in which adaptations are based entirely on analyses of non-comparative data, that is, without incorporating information about treatment assignment. Such analyses are sometimes called blinded or masked analyses. In general, adequately prespecified adaptations based on non-comparative data have no effect or a limited effect on the Type I error probability. This makes them an attractive choice in many settings, particularly when uncertainty about event probabilities or endpoint variability is high.

They are saying that these studies are non-comparative or blinded. But in case of blinded data we have DMC in place and for DMC it is comparative data hence I am confused. Or the aim of such interim analyses is not to compare the treatment effect but rather to have nuisance parameters updated? And treatment effect is only estimated at the final analysis?

"Or the aim of such interim analyses is not to compare the treatment effect but rather to have nuisance parameters updated? And treatment effect is only estimated at the final analysis?" This is correct. This is what is meant by non-comparative data.
